# Llenar formularios web desde consola Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, dom, consola, google-chrome

Tengo un formulario web que lo tengo que rellenar desde la consola de "Chrome". En los casilleros de texto no tengo problemas. Uso por ejemplo:

```
txtNombre.value='nombre';
```

Pero en los casilleros de lista de `select` no se como puedo seleccionar una opción desde la consola. ¿Cómo sería en este caso?
este es el codigo:

```
    <tr>
    <td>Gender</td>
    <td>
        <div class="select2-container" id="s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice select2-default select2-required" tabindex="-1">   
    <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-2">Select an Option</span>
    <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
    <b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen2" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-2" id="s2id_autogen2" tabindex="0"></div>
    <select name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:personDetails:genderDropDownList" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList" onchange="nzis.UpdateDropdownErrorLabel(this)" errorlabel="mandatory" tabindex="-1" title="" style="display: none;">
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="F">Female</option>

    </select>

    </td>
</tr>
```

desde la consola de chrome deberia poder poner en el casillero de Gender la opcion Male.

Comment: Bienvenido. Mencionas que es lo que has intentado en un caso pero en el caso específico que te interesa. Es importante que busques/investigues. Referencia: [ask].

Comment: Lo se..  no eh encontrado respuesta a mi solicitud, soy muy novato en esto tambien. En mi caso no puedo seleccionar desde la consola de chrome un item de una lista desplegable.  si alguein me puede ayudar

Comment: Pero añade al menos como es el formato del "casillero de lista de `select`"

Comment: Las buenas preguntas generalmente tienen votos positivos y mayores probabilidades de obtener una buena respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes escribir esto en la consola

```
document.getElementById("download-document").value = "book";
```

En este caso lo hice en la [página oficial de Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html)

En el apartado Documentación Offline hay dos select el primero es en el que cambio el valor. Si no quieres comprobar en esa url, solo tienes que reemplazar el parámetro pasado en getElementById por el id del select que quieres cambiar su valor y asignarle el valor de la propiedad **value** de uno de sus options.

por ejemplo supongamos que tienes una página que tiene esta forma

```
<select name="paises" id="paises_select">
  <option>Seleccione un pais</option>
  <option value="ES">España</option>
  <option value="EU">Estados Unidos</option>
  <option value="BR">Brasil</option>
</select>
```

Y digamos que quieres seleccionar España, pues puedes hacer una de las dos opciones siguientes

```
document.getElementById("paises_select").value = "ES";
```

**O**

```
//Si estuviera dentro de un formulario llamado form1 sería form.paises.value = "ES" sino
paises.value = "ES";
```